# Inserting a single string text file with multi character delimiters into a spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark

New to spark and I am learning as I go. I have a very large text file with columns delimited by "|||||" that I would like to insert into a spark dataframe. However, the file is just one line string. The file looks something like this:

```
col1|||||col2|||||col3|||||col4|||||col5|||||col1|||||col2|||||col3...
```

So column 1 through 5 just essentially loop in the one line. I've tried to insert a new line after every 5th "|||||" with a sed command via:

```
 sed -r 's/([^|||||]*|||||){5}/&\n/g'
```

Which worked the most part but ultimately ended up not working properly for some reason. I suspect col4 (which is an enormous text field) is causing some issues in this but I do not know enough as to why it is doing so.

Now when I read the single line text file into spark via:

```
val df = spark.read.textFile(file)
```

This puts everything into one column, and I would like to split it out into 5 columns and kind of have the dataframe "wrap" the string after every 5 columns.

My Goal is to get it into something like this:

```
+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|                col1|           col2|                col3|                col4|                col5|
+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|                 val|            val|                 val|                 val|                 val|
|                 val|            val|                 val|                 val|                 val|
+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

So my question is: Because my file is just one massive string, is there a way to get the dataframe to enter a new record/row after 5 columns?

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution to your first question.
Usually You would read as a regular text file and later use the split method to convert the line into columns.

```
df.withColumn("tmp", split($"value", "|||||")).select(
  $"tmp".getItem(0).as("first"),
  $"tmp".getItem(1).as("second"),
  $"tmp".getItem(2).as("third")
).drop("tmp")
```

For your second question. You can use this regex to match the pattern:

> (([a-z0-9A-Z]+)(\|\|\|\|\|)([a-z0-9A-Z]+)(\|\|\|\|\|)([a-z0-9A-Z]+)(\|\|\|\|\|)([a-z0-9A-Z]+)(\|\|\|\|\|))

If you have enough memory you can read all your file and then use this pattern to extract the parts of it.

If not then you have to read it byte by byte and see if you match this pattern.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If the file is big with a single line, then go with Perl solution. Perl variables can store file contents ( even in GBs) and you can manage easily. You do all the preprocessing in perl itself. See if the below works for you

```
> cat 5cols
col1|||||col2|||||col3|||||col4|||||col5|||||col1|||||col2|||||col3|||||col4|||||col5|||||col1|||||col2|||||col3|||||col4|||||col5|||||col1|||||col2|||||col3|||||col4|||||col5|||||col1|||||col2|||||col3|||||col4|||||col5|||||col1|||||col2|||||col3|||||col4|||||col5|||||col1|||||col2|||||col3|||||col4|||||col5|||||col1|||||col2|||||col3|||||col4|||||col5|||||col1|||||col2|||||col3|||||col4|||||col5|||||col1|||||col2|||||col3|||||col4|||||col5|||||

> perl -e ' BEGIN {$x=qx(cat 5cols);while($x=~m/([^|]+?)(?=[|]{5})/g){ print "$1,\n"} exit } ' | xargs -n5 | sed 's/,$//g'
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5

>
```

Redirect the above output to another csv file. Now, you can read with spark.csv as a regular csv file with 5 columns